# What do the exclamation marks with red borders mean on the Boston map?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

On the Boston map of Assassin's Creed 3, I see an exclamation mark with a red border. When I go to them on the map, I see a person wearing civilian clothing, with a gun, running. What are they?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps supply a screenshot too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the below Youtube video, it's a courier mission. This also matches your description of a person in civilian clothes running. You can see the icon at about 35 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

<s>An exclamation mark indicates the main story-line mission. Once you go there you'll see a marker and this will either start you on a new mission or it acts as a checkpoint if you are already in a mission.</s>

I haven't played AC-3 but in the other games that icon indicated either a pickpocket or a courier. So you will have to chase the civilian clothed person who is running and grab him, default is shift key on PC. This will give you a reward of some kind and possibly increase notoriety. In case of pickpocketers doing this will help regain the money they stole from you.

Comment: sorry but the icon i am talking about is an exclamation mark with a red border shaped as a badge. It randomly appears on the map, and when I go to that icon there is no interaction or mission event, the icon (person) just runs away from me and shouts "Stay away from me" so i just kill him and nothing happens afterwards.

Comment: Could you add a screen-shot to your question?

Comment: added screenshot